# Fixed and Reserved Outbound IP for App Service

Tags: web-services, azure, app-service-environment

I have an azure web app that has 2 slots (one for production and one for staging). My web app calls an external web service that is protected via IP filtering. When I'm in production, I call the external web service for production and when I'm in staging I call the external web service for staging.

Because I switch from staging to production my 2 outbound IP adresses change regularly. So the external web service cannot protect independently staging and production.

Can the App Service Environnement can help me? Or another Azure service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you're out of luck here. According to [Microsoft Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/):

> **Can I use a reserved IP for all Azure services?**
>
> Reserved IPs can only be used for VMs and cloud service instance roles exposed through a VIP.

So, no reserved IPs for Azure App Services, but only for VMs and Cloud Services.

But there might be some solutions possible:

- replace IP filtering with Azure subdomain filtering, such as my-app-prod.azurewebsites.net, my-app-staging.azurewebsites.net (or buy a domain name and set its subdomain records to point to Azure App Service slot subdomains and use them instead of Azure's)
- migrate your environment to Azure Cloud Services or VMs and then set up Azure Virtual Network with reserved IP addresses.